# How to get all Fields names in golang proto generated complex structs

Tags: go, struct, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-go

I am trying to get all the fields names in the go file generated from proto.
Below is the generated struct.

```golang
type Action struct {
    Name             string            `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
    // Types that are valid to be assigned to ActionType:
    //  *Action_TaskAction
    ActionType           isAction_ActionType `protobuf_oneof:"action_type"`
}
```

As it is seen that ActionType is oneof Field in proto which is implemented as below.

```golang
type isAction_ActionType interface {
    isAction_ActionType()
}

type Action_TaskAction struct {
    TaskAction *TaskAction `protobuf:"bytes,16,opt,name=task_action,json=taskAction,proto3,oneof"`
}

type TaskAction struct {
    Progress             float32  `protobuf:"fixed32,1,opt,name=progress,proto3" json:"progress,omitempty"`
}
```

As I want to get the field name in TaskAction struct which is Progress.

I am using below code to get the field names but facing issue if the field type is interface(for oneof field)

```golang
func printFieldNames(t reflect.Type) error {
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            printFieldNames(field.Type)
            continue
        }
        if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
            // what to do here.
        }
        column := field.Tag.Get("json")
        fmt.Println("column: ", column)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type is interface, you can't do much about that. In an actual value it may be a struct or any other type that implements that interface, but the interface *type* itself cannot tell you this, it does not restrict the concrete type.

You may do what you want if you start with [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) instead of [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type), because if you have a value, you can examine the value (or its type) that is stored in the interface. To get the `reflect.Value` descriptor wrapped in an interface value, you may use [`reflect.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem).

Also, to handle pointer to structs, you again may use `reflect.Elem()` to get the pointed value. You may check if a value is a pointer by comparing its kind to `reflect.Ptr`.

Here's an example of your `printFieldNames()`, rewritten to work with `reflect.Value`, and it recurses into structs stored in interface values. This is not a solution that handles all cases, but demonstrates how to do it:

```
func printFieldNames(v reflect.Value) {
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        field := v.Field(i)
        if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            field = field.Elem()
        }
        if field.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            printFieldNames(field)
            continue
        }
        if field.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
            wrapped := field.Elem()
            if wrapped.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                wrapped = wrapped.Elem()
            }
            printFieldNames(wrapped)
        }
        structfield := v.Type().Field(i)
        column := structfield.Tag.Get("json")
        fmt.Printf("column: %s, json tag: %s\n", structfield.Name, column)
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
a := Action{
    ActionType: Action_TaskAction{
        TaskAction: &TaskAction{},
    },
}
printFieldNames(reflect.ValueOf(a))
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dex4v0LnEnX)):

```
column: Name, json tag: name,omitempty
column: Progress, json tag: progress,omitempty
column: ActionType, json tag:
```

Comment: another related question: how to get the value with the name? I didn't find a good answer to how to iterate the pb struct. thanks.

Comment: @city Please post a new question with all the details.