# Extract FIELD names of a struct and put them in a slice of strings

Tags: go, struct, raylib

I want to be able to extract the FIELD names (not the values) of a struct as strings, put them in a slice of strings and then use the names to print in a menu in Raylib (a graphics library for Go) elsewhere in a program. That way if I change the fields in the struct the menu will update automatically without having to go back and manually edit it. So, if you take a look at the struct below, I want to extract the names MOVING, SOLID, OUTLINE etc. not the boolean value. Is there a way to do this?

```
type genatt struc {
    moving, solid, outline, gradient, rotating bool
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to do this. Acquire the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptor of the struct value, and use `Type.Field()` to access the fields.

For example:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(genatt{})

names := make([]string, t.NumField())
for i := range names {
    names[i] = t.Field(i).Name
}

fmt.Println(names)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JDiP6GaVY08)):

```
[moving solid outline gradient rotating]
```

See related questions:

[How to get all Fields names in golang proto generated complex structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885851/how-to-get-all-fields-names-in-golang-proto-generated-complex-structs/57886310#57886310)

[How to sort struct fields in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913483/how-to-sort-struct-fields-in-alphabetical-order/30915092#30915092)

[What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly and was exactly what I wanted, thanks. If I want a list of field types as strings how would I do that? For example [int float32 string int] so instead of the names in the slice, it is the field type as a string in the slice?

Comment: If you only want to add `string` fields, then check the type's kind: `t.Field(i).Type.Kind() == reflect.String`.